# Ubuntu 22.04. It takes several minutes to detect the touchpad after booting up

Tags: boot, touchpad, input-devices

I've used my laptop disk on a desktop for a couple of weeks, and after putting it back into laptop I get errors (listed on the screenshot) while booting up. After the system is booted the touchpad won't work for several minutes, after which all goes to normal.
[Hardware logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sPcl.png)
[Logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuPCr.png)
[Touchpad as shown in devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxih9.png)